# vb.net Find class instance where property = query

Tags: vb.net, class

I have a custom class called "game".  Say I create 3 instances of this class.

```
Public Class FrmMain
  Public Sub addGames()
    for x As Integer = 1 To 3 Step 1
      Dim game As New game
      if x = 1 then game.name = "Zelda"
      if x = 2 then game.name = "Mario"
      if x = 3 then game.name = "Donkey Kong"
    next
  End Sub

  Public Sub findMario()
    'What goes here?
  End Sub
End Class
```

What do I put in my sub "findMario()" to get the instance of "game" the name property equal to "Mario"?

Comment: Won't `game.name` always be "Donkey Kong" after addGames() runs?  You only define one game, and then give it three different names in rapid succession.  The last name you assigned is the name it keeps.

Comment: grrr, you're right, so pretend that problem doesn't exist :D

Comment: So, before you can find Mario, you'll need to change what `addGames()` is doing.  Is the `game` variable from `addGames()` even visible to `findMario()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
Public Class FrmMain
    Dim games as new List(of game)

    Public Sub addGames()
        games.Add(New Game With {.Name = "Zelda"})
        games.Add(New Game With {.Name = "Mario"})
        games.Add(New Game With {.Name = "Donkey Kong"})
    End Sub

    Public Sub findMario()
        Dim result = (From game In games
                     Where game.Name.Equals("Mario")
                     Select game).FirstOrDefault

        'Do something with the result
    End Sub
End Class
```

If you need to retrieve the game names from an external text file you could do something like this:

```
Public Sub addGames()
    Dim names = File.ReadAllLines("C:\games.txt")        

    names.ToList().ForEach(Sub(x) games.Add(New Game With {.Name = x}))
End Sub
```

Comment: This should work the same, right?

Dim newGame = New game |
newGame.name = sr.ReadLine 'gamename |
games.Add(newGame) |

Comment: Yep, that should be fine. I'll update my answer with an example of alternative syntax for reading the game names from a file.